# Mechanism of import directory's file in python

Tags: python

I'm try to import a module in a package in such a directory structure. And I found a very amazing thing which I could not find the explanation.

```py
➜  test tree
.
├── main.py
└── package
    └── module.py
```

If the `main.py` is

```
import package
package.module
```

The there will be an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    package.module
AttributeError: module 'package' has no attribute 'module'
```

If the `main.py` is

```
import package
from package import module
package.module
```

or

```
from package import module
import package
package.module
```

Nothing error.

The result is same even tough I add a `__init__.py` in `package`

It's annoying that I have the to do a extra command to import a module in a package.

I think there should be a elegant way to do this and I also want to know the mechanism of this phenomenon. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Python thinks you are importing a module when you do `import package`, which you can also see in the exception description (says `module 'package'`):

```
AttributeError: module 'package' has no attribute 'module'
```

You should import AND look for the module directly:

```
from package import module
module
```

If you want a specific function/class, you do:

```
from package.module import Class
instance = Class()
```

Concerning what you observe with the two import statements, Python seems to keep a reference of the package the module came from, so it allows chaining the names when both of them are imported separately. But the chaining is not really needed. If you want to keep a reference of the package that the module came from, consult the `module.__name__` property, or use `as`:

```
from package import module as 'package_module'
print(package_module.__name__) # returns 'package.module'
```

Although that is ugly.